# Reset the appearance of navigation bar in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have disabled the bottom border line (shadow image) of the navigation bar using:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default) 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

But after locking the device and unlocking it again the bottom border line appears. I was able to hide it again by using the above code in **viewWillAppear:**

But I would like to know what's causing the navigation bar to reset to it default configuration each time it appears?

As I am **unable** to make the shadow line reappear in another ViewController using below code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default) 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

I would like to know how to reset the navigation bar appearance to make the bottom border line(shadow image) reappear?

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking device will NOT call viewWillAppear, May be you are using a BaseViewController with adding Notification Observer on UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Try using Appearance instead on AppDelegate

```swift
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

And Reappear the line again

```swift
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But the above code is not working for making the bottom line reappear again. I have seen in other answers that it is the right code to do so, but it currently does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create `UINavigationViewController` extension with a handy function to do it:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {

    func resetToDefaultAppearance() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()

        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Then call it in your `viewWillDisappear`:

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    navigationController?.resetToDefaultAppearance()
}
```